# Order of elements in set of pointers

Tags: c++, set

Why does the following code get compiled even though I have commented the `A::operator<`. I wonder how the output of the following code is printed in ascending order without the `<` operator. How can I change the order to descending? (*note*: this code does not get compiled if I use `A` instead of `A*` unless I provide a definition for `A::operator<`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(int v):x(v){}
    virtual ~A(){}
    int x;
    /*bool operator<(const A &a) const
    {
        return x > a.x;
    }*/
};

int main()
{
    set<A*> numbers;
    A* a1 = new A(1);
    A* a2 = new A(2);
    A* a3 = new A(3);
    numbers.insert(a2);
    numbers.insert(a3);
    numbers.insert(a1);
    for(set<A*>::iterator itr = numbers.begin();itr!=numbers.end();itr++)
    {
        cout << (*itr)->x << endl;
    }
    // output: 1 2 3
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: P.s. The order of the "insert" is irrelevant. a set ALWAYS keep it values in order using some `<`. if it couldn't use a `<` it won't compile.

Comment: It's just dumb luck. It could be printed in any order. It just so happens that `a1 < a2 < a3` because that's what your allocator does. If you change the `1, 2, 3` to `3, 2, 1`, you'll get `3, 2, 1` out.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your code gets compiled because you have a set of pointers. Since the set contains pointers, and your operator does not compare pointers, but rather, objects of type `A`, it is not needed for the set. There is an existing pointer less-than comparison operator, which is what gets used in your set.

You can change the ordering by providing your own comparator implementing [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html):

```
struct APtrComp
{
  bool operator()(const A* lhs, const A* rhs) const  { /* implement logic here */ }
};
```

And instantiate your set using it as second template parameter.

```
set<A*, APtrComp> numbers;
```

Comment: That's almost right.  There is an existing `<` for pointers, but it's behavior is unspecified (and not necessarily consistent) for pointers resulting from different allocations.  `std::set<>` uses `std::less<>` by default, however, and not `<`.  And an implementation is required to make `std::less` work for pointers.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks for the clarification. I was wrongly assuming that `std::less` would just call the `<` operator in this case.

Comment: @juanchopanza, this solution has a problem, it does NOT maintain the raw pointer duplicate comparison.  See my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115682/how-to-represent-a-set-of-pointers-with-customized-compare-but-maintaining-the-o

Comment: @PeterLee I don't see a problem with that, neither does OP. Their use-case may be different to yours.

Comment: @PeterLee I had a quick look. Ordering and "identity" or "equality" are one and the same thing in `std::set`, so I am not sure how you can achieve what you want without a dedicated data structure.

Answer (score 3):

you have a set of pointers. usually pointers are allocated in increasing order. and pointers have a default `<` operator. so this is why it's compiling and working.

P.s. it will print you the value of A1 A2 A3 in this order no matter what's there values:

```
...
A* a1 = new A(9);
A* a2 = new A(5);
A* a3 = new A(1);
...
 // output: 9 5 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remember your pointer arithmetic, all points are given a set of operators to use in operations(which includes the operator<). Your set will use this default operator < .

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to know why the code compiles with `A*` even if you dont have the `operator<` and how to change the order from ascending to descending.

It compiles because it is using the `operator<` with the pointers address.
change `cout << (*itr)->x << endl;` 
to `cout << (*itr)->x << ' ' << *itr << endl;` and you'll see it easily :)

It is normal that the code doesn't compile without the `operator<` if you're using the `set<A>`. It won't know what to compare in order to insert the members sorted. So you have to provide that operator!

If you want to keep using pointers, you can use the code provided by @juanchopanza.