# How to Represent a Set of Pointers with Customized Compare but Maintaining the Original Raw Pointer Duplicate Comparison

Tags: c++, pointers, set

Basically, I want to save a set of pointers, which should be sorted by my customized compare function, but the uniqueness should still be determined by the pointer itself.

However:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

//         count, word
typedef pair<int, string> WordFreq;

struct WordFreqPointerCmp
{
    bool operator()(const WordFreq* lhs, const WordFreq* rhs) const
    {
        return lhs->first > rhs->first;
    }
};

int main()
{
    set<WordFreq*, WordFreqPointerCmp> s;
    s.insert(new WordFreq(1, "word1")); // Inserted
    s.insert(new WordFreq(1, "word2")); // This is not inserted
    s.insert(new WordFreq(3, "word3")); // Inserted

    cout << s.size() << endl;

    for (set<WordFreq*, WordFreqPointerCmp>::iterator it = s.begin();
         it != s.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << (*it)->second << ": " << (*it)->first << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
/* Output:
2
word3: 3
word1: 1
 */
```

As you can see that the ordering is correct, but the duplicate testing is wrong.  What I am trying to do is:

- For ordering, I want to use `WordFreqPointerCmp`;
- For duplicate testing, I want to use the original meaning of raw Pointer comparsion, i.e., the address comparison, which means, even the following set should have two entries in the set;

  ```
  set<WordFreq*, WordFreqPointerCmp> s;
  s.insert(new WordFreq(1, "word1"));
  s.insert(new WordFreq(1, "word1"));
  ```

I also tried the following, but same result:

```
template<>
struct greater<WordFreq*>
{
    bool operator()(WordFreq* const& lhs, WordFreq* const& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs->first > rhs->first;
    }
};
set<WordFreq*, greater<WordFreq*> > s;
```

Comment: Probably you meant set<WordFreq*> s;

Comment: Yes Or No, if I just use `set<WordFreq*> s`, the duplicate testing is correct, but how can I use a customized comparer?

Answer (score 1):

while this post is ancient, I've just faced the same issue, so it may help somebody..

In your code you only handle one value, but what if values are the same? Then set treats it as the same element. The proper solution would be to extend your compare function to give set additional information how to test for duplicates. It can be something arbitrary like comparing strings, for example in your case:

```
struct WordFreqPointerCmp
{
    bool operator()(const WordFreq* lhs, const WordFreq* rhs) const
    {
        if (lhs->first == rhs->first)
            return lhs->second > rhs->second;
        else
            return lhs->first > rhs->first;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem is. Since you want the first component of your pair to be the key that determines uniqueness, inserting two "WordFreq" with key = 1 should lead to the second evict the first. Results match expectation here.

**Update**: I guess, I misunderstood something. Since you want duplicate keys, you are probably looking for [multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/).

**Update 2**: To make this work you need to add a step before adding a new object: Iterate over all values of the same key, and kick those out that point to the object being added. Also, I forgot to mention there is [multiset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/) which is probably what you'd prefer.

I admit, here is where Java's [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) with it's separate order and equality tests come in handy. Maybe you can find a C++ version of it.

Comment: Like I said, I want my set auto-sorted by my customized Compare function, but the uniqueness should still be determined by the raw pointer.

Comment: No. You are still misunderstanding. As I said, the uniqueness should still be determined by the raw pointers, but the sorting should be using my customized compare.